# IntelliJ IDEA disable editing/formatting .svg images in a project

Tags: java, svg, intellij-idea

I have a `.svg` image in a project. And each time when made any change in the code (not in this file), IDEA edits/re-formats this `.svg` file in the background. So, it has become part of changes for a new commit. Therefore, I have to roll back changes.

How to disable these background changes in IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about *background* changes but there is a useful option in IntelliJ that may be relevant.
By selecting this option, when *you* reformat the code explicitly (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Windows), it will just reformat new (uncommitted) changes to file.

Top menu bar: *Code* ➜ *Reformat File...* ➜ *Scope* ➜  *Only changes uncommitted to VCS*